# Yii select mysql process list

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I want excecute command `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`

```
$process = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST");
$data = $process->query();
```

But query not returning records

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `queryAll()` or `queryRow()` instead of `query()`, like below:

```
$process = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST");
$data = $process->queryAll();

CVarDumper::dump($data); //will show you the result
```

In cases you need to fetch row, you can use `queryRow()`, like below:

```
$process = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST");
$data = $process->queryRow();
```

To be more familiar with differences, `queryAll()` executes the SQL statement and returns all rows while `queryRow()` executes the SQL statement and returns the first row of the result. In front, `query()` returns `CDbDataReader` object instead of result array. If you get a dump from above query with `query()` you will see the following result:

```
CDbDataReader#1
(
[CDbDataReader:_statement] => PDOStatement#2
(
    [queryString] => 'SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST'
)
[CDbDataReader:_closed] => false
[CDbDataReader:_row] => null
[CDbDataReader:_index] => -1
[CComponent:_e] => null
[CComponent:_m] => null
)
```